# Update cells in tables in header in word document using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have opened a word document in vb.net. This word document has table in header and in the document.
I tried updating a table in document it works fine. But not able to succeed in updating table which is in header. Need help to know the syntax to update the table in header.

```
'update table
Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
oTable = oDoc.Tables(1)
oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
For r = 1 To 1
For c = 1 To 4
oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "r" & r & "c" & c
Next
Next

'update table in header
Dim footerRange As Word.Range = oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Tables
footerRange.Cells(1).Range.Text = "RR"
```

Error:

> The requested member of the collection does not exist.

in:

```
Dim footerRange As Word.Range = oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range‌​.Tables(1)
```

Thanks and Regards
Siva.P

Comment: In the below line there is a error message "The requested member of the collection does not exist."
'update table in header
Dim footerRange As Word.Range = oDoc.Sections(1).Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage).Range.Tables(1)

Comment: That error just says your referencing an index that does not exist either Sections(1) or Tables (1) is the incorrect index to reference

Comment: How to correct this?

Comment: Any luck in solving your problem 2022?

Answer (score 0):

WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage will only work if you've set your document up to have a different header on the first page, if your table is in all headers then it's falling over when trying to access `.Tables(1)`

So if your table is in all headers across the document use `WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary` as the index for the headers